# What is the technology of slicing a chip to debug called?

Tags: microprocessor, semiconductors, debugging

A couple of times, I have heard that there are situations where a microprocesor or chip has to be sliced to look in to the contents, or for the purpose of debugging it. Layer by layer sectioning is performed is my understanding. I did google search but since this information came to me through friend circles, I couldnt find the exact technology used to do so. Please help me understand better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what technology you mean as there are **many**. Go [here](https://eesemi.com/fa-techniques.htm) to see a list.

Find more by searching for "Semiconductor Failure Analysis".

"Slicing a chip" is destructive and not so much for debugging as for **reverse engineering**.

When designers know what the bug is and want to make circuit changes and/or experiment to confirm their findings, usually non-destrictive methods are used like Focussed Ion Beam (FIB) to make small changes to the circuits on a chip.